# Send automatic message on a given date

Tags: java, sms, quartz-scheduler, sinch

I have made a SMS application with Java that works like a charm. I want the application to send SMS on a given date. I am using the Quartz Job Scheduling for that. First I need these two applications to be connected to each other. Then I need Quartz to collect a date and time from a list (can be excel list) and send a message. Is this possible? Appreciate any help.

Here is the message application:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class SMSApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String phoneNumber = "+XXXXXXXXX";
            String appKey = "XXXXXXX";
            String appSecret = "XXXXXXXX";
            String message = "Hello world!";

            URL url = new URL("https://messagingapi.sinch.com/v1/sms/" + phoneNumber);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            String userCredentials = "application\\" + appKey + ":" + appSecret;
            byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(userCredentials.getBytes());
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(encoded);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

            String postData = "{\"Message\":\"" + message + "\"}";
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(postData.getBytes());

            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(line);

            br.close();
            os.close();

            System.out.println(response.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the Quartz job class:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class QuartzJob implements Job{

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {

            System.out.println("Hello");
            System.out.println(new Date())
    }
   }
```

And here is the Quartz main class:

```
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.ScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;


public class QuartzMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {

        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzJob.class).build();

        Trigger tl = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("SimpleTrigger").startNow().build();

        Scheduler sc = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

        sc.start();
        sc.scheduleJob(job, tl);

    }}
```

Comment: " Is this possible? Appreciate any help.", this is very broad and vague- Could you be more specific in your question what your asking about and how it relates to the code posted?

Comment: I am so sorry. I am quite new in this forum and very new to programming. I basically do not know how to connect the SMS app and Quartz? I have seen a couple of examples with emails instead of SMS, but I did still not understand which part of the code that did connect them. I simply want to tell the Quartz app to send a message using the SMS app.

Comment: Hey, why dont you just move the code (or make a class that is not main out of the sms functionality adn move it to yoru job where you print hello world

Comment: Thats a great idea. Which method is best? Move the code or make a class? Do you also know how I can incorporate the SMS class to take action when Quartz is activated?

Answer (score 0):

To start at a given date:

In the trigger replace `.startNow()` with `.startAt(date)` with date being a `java.util.Date` that represents the date and time it should start.

To connect:

In your Quartz job class call your sendSMS() method (currently your main method in SMSApplication) any variables (such as the phone number) should be passed to the job class in the job builer with `.usingJobData("key","value")`. See http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/ and read through the Tutorials and Cookbook for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helps me a lot.